# Shortcode in Wordpress causes Openserver death

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

So I have a custom PHP page in Wordpress that displays some content:

```
<? while(have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?the_content();?>
<? endwhile; ?>
```

I need to display the list of news related with this content, so I wrote a shortcode for that:

```
function generate_program_news(){
 $news_args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'cat' => 4);
 $news_query = new WP_Query($news_args);
 $news_data;
 while( $news_query->have_posts() ) {
   $news_date = get_permalink();
   $news_title = the_title();
   $news_data = "<a>" .$news_date. ": " .$news_title. "</a>";
 }
 wp_reset_postdata();
 return $news_data;
}

add_shortcode('program_news','generate_program_news');
```

But when I add [program_news] shortcode and try to access the page I used it in, the entire website dies off until I have the OpenServer rebooted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does mean "dies off"? I see a syntax error in return statement: `return $news-data;` should be `return $news_data;`

Comment: @ksno it doesn't open any pages and the WP admin panel opened in another tab says 'Lost connection to server'. Sorry about the variable in **return**, it is correct in actual code, so this is not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while( $news_query->have_posts() )
```

you must type

```
$news_query->the_post();
```

Comment: Oh jeez, what a stupid mistake. Thank you very much.